# Tag cleanup, episodes XIII-XVII

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-cleanup

Some of these I could probably do myself, but I figure I've already cluttered the front page enough today.

1. Rename [lipo](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lipo) (55) to [lithium-polymer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lithium-polymer), it's more formal
2. Rename [mains](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains) (59) to [mains-electricity](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains-electricity) (0: doesn't exist yet), make [line-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-power) (34) a synonym
3. Make [charging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging) (57) a synonym of [battery-charging](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery-charging) (240)

   - maybe [charger](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charger) (101) as well, but the tag excerpt for that also includes cap charging, and I just retagged a question as such...
4. Make either [dc-dc-converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-dc-converter) (34) or [dc-dc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-dc) (92) point to the other (the former maybe).
5. Make [bldc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bldc) (26) [brushless](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless) (24) and [brushless-dc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless-dc) (9) synonyms of [brushless-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless-motor) (0)

Comment: I have cleaned up all the tags aside from the lipo, which I think is OK for now.

Answer (score 2):

I plan on merging/synonym [bldc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bldc), [brushless](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless), [brushless-dc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless-dc) into a new tag [brushless-dc-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless-dc-motor). This preserves the spirit of clarifying acronyms while catching all (hopefully) alternate usages.

Comment: This has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

I plan on merging [line-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-power) and [mains](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains), with the intent that the resulting tag cover normal residential power delivery and wiring from the output of the last utility-owned transformer to the circuitry that directly interacts with the power line for the purpose of supplying power. I propose using the [mains](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains) as the master tag as I don't see the benefit from changing it to [mains-electricity](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains-electricity).

Questions looking to use the house wiring for communication should be tagged [power-line-communication](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-line-communication)

Questions currently tagged [powerline](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerline) should be manually retagged to either [power-distribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-distribution) for power grid topics, or [mains](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains)/[power-line-communication](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-line-communication) as appropriate.

Questions tagged [grid](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid) have significant overlap with [power-distribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-distribution) and propose merging and synonym the two into [power-distribution](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-distribution).

I know I've thrown a lot together here. If you have specific objections, please comment.

Comment: This has been completed

Answer (score -2):

I'd make lithium-polymer a synonym at best. While more formal, lipo is wildly used like nimh or nicad or usb or any acronym/abbreviation.

Comment: The nice part about a synonym though is that someone can type one and get the other. Do you think anyone would see lithium-polymer who not understand what was meant but would understand lipo?

Comment: Some abbreviations are OK, but even then you have to at least spell them correctly.  I probably wouldn't immediately recognize "nimh" or "nicad" unless they were spelled "NiMH" and "NiCd".  Details matter, especially on a international list where you're already on thin ice with abbreviations.