# Proposed Tag Merging

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Should the [usb](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb) tag and the [usb-device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-device) tag be merged?
Over half of the 79 [usb-device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-device) tagged questions are also tagged [usb](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb), and a good majority of usb tagged questions are simply about usb devices, not just the protocol.

[sd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd) and [microsd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsd) should be merged as well. [microsd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsd) should become a synonym, as a Microsd card is simply a different form factor of SD cards, with no electrical or protocol changes. Nothing special or unique about it.

Finally, [preamp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preamp) and [amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amplifier) should be merged. A preamp is simply a small Amplifier. Preamp should become a synonym (I just suggested it as well).

---

Resolved <strike>[one-wire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-wire) should be a synonym of [1-wire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-wire). 1-Wire is the proper protocol name (I have already corrected the few tagged questions, but can't suggest a synonym because I don't have 5 votes in that tag yet).</strike>

Resolved <strike>[dc-dc-converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-dc-converter) and [dc-dc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-dc) should be combined. Personally, Dc-Dc-Converter is more descriptive a name, even though the dc-dc tag has the wiki already in it.</strike>

Addressed in [Tag cleanup, episodes XIII-XVII](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/tag-cleanup-episodes-xiii-xvii) <strike>[line-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-power) and [mains](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mains). The excerpts are identical. Is there a practical difference? Should be merged and synonymized. As should [powerline](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerline), though Line-Power or Mains should be the surviving one. Not to be confused with the [powerline-communications](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerline-communications)</strike>

Resolved <strike>[ptc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ptc) should become a synonym of [polyfuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyfuse), as PPTC has already become.</strike>

Resolved <strike>[fuses](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuses) should become a synonym of [fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuse) as well.</strike>

Comment: Well, if anything, @W5Vo edit showed me how to add tag links, which I've made plenty of use for updating tag wikis.

Comment: I'm going to address the line-power / mains / powerline in [this question][http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/tag-cleanup-episodes-xiii-xvii] since it was asked there first.

Answer (score 5):

- Merging USB with USB-device: "USB" tagged questions are ideally to do with the protocol and its implementation in one's code, not with a USB device. On the other hand, "USB-device" questions may not care a whit about the protocol and firmware, and be all about device hardware, voltages, using USB as a power source for a device, and so on.

  Not a good candidate for a merge.
- Preamp and Amplifier: While a preamp is certainly a small amplifier, a microcontroller is also a small computer. No, they have different target audiences, very different problems and challenges, and deserve to be kept separate.

Comment: Out of the 14 questions in the Preamp tag, only 2 or 3 would really qualify as different from Amplifier questions. Have you taken a look at them?

Comment: The merit of a distinctive tag is not weighed by popularity, but by distinct purpose. At best, editing the tag wikis to explain the distinction would work, not merging two very distinct application areas.

Comment: "USB-device" is to distinguish from "USB-host", no?

Comment: @markrages the usb-host tag is properly targeted, and not nearly as overlapping as usb-device is.

Comment: @markrages and USB-OTG as well

Answer (score 4):

I propose a synonym of [microsd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsd) into [sd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd), and approving [sd-card](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd-card) as a synonym of [sd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd). Please up/down vote to indicate preference.

Answer (score 3):

[fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuse) is now a synonym of [fuses](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fuses)

[amps](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amps) is now a synonym of [amperage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amperage)

[dc-dc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-dc) has been merged into [dc-dc-converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-dc-converter) and is now a synonym as well

[ptc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ptc) is now a synonym of [polyfuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyfuse). The one Q using it for a RTD was retagged.

[one-wire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-wire) is now a synonym or [1-wire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-wire)

The rest I believe are not as clear-cut for me to pick a primary tag, or may have disagreements on whether the synonym is appropriate. If you feel strongly about them, bring them up in a single post (only one tag merge/synonym per post) so everyone can express an opinion on them clearly.

For now, the [line-power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line-power) debate will be held on [this question][http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/tag-cleanup-episodes-xiii-xvii] because he asked about it first. I want to see some votes on the [sd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd)/[microsd](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsd)/[sd-card](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd-card) merge/synonym, so vote on my other answer to express support or dislike.

Based on the Anindo's response (and the votes/comments there), I am going to leave the [usb-device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-device) and [preamp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preamp) tags alone.

Comment: Agree with all of your mergers, except for ptc-polyfuse.  Every polyfuse is a PTC.  But, there are PTC thermistors that aren't fuses.  This nuance should be mentioned in the excerpts for these tags.  But, again they shouldn't be actual synonyms.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I did make sure that I didn't get any thermistor questions with the merge. The vast majority were polyfuse related. I'm possibly misusing the synonym feature to keep the PTC tag from coming back. We can definitely add a note in the tag excerpt.

Comment: Let's re-label the ones that have the PTC-as-fuse meaning to `polyfuse` , and undo the synonym.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Done. If the PTC tag keeps coming back, and everyone uses the PTC tag as a synonym for polyfuse, then we might bring it back